# Vue.js & Node.js - Should I upload images to vue (front end) or node (back end)

Tags: node.js, image, vue.js, file-upload

I woulod like to make an image upload component saving uploaded image name to DB.

But where should I upload the image itself?

Store it in `uploads/` inside `vue.js` or pass whole image to backend `node.js` and store it there?

What would be the best practice of it?

Comment: Vue.js is a front end library what does it mean to upload an image there

Comment: @perusopersonale I mean vue.js project directory or node.js project directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used vue.js, from what I know is a client library like React, so if you want to upload an image you have to pass the whole image to a backend.

The best practice I think would be store the image in some remote filesystem, like a S3 and store the reference in a db

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we only talking about a few, then front end. But if there are lots, or they are large, then back-end